# Android Studio freezing constantly

Tags: android, android-studio

My android project has over 30 build flavors and I started seeing the slowdown. Android Studio just keeps freezing whenever I type a character or add a new line.

Filed a bug with Google but haven't heard back.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling Instant Run?

I would need more info on your config but it sounds like you probably have Instant Run enabled. The larger and more complex your project becomes, the higher the impact on IDE performance.

If you haven’t tried already, it’s worth a shot:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

Answer (score 0):

You may need to uninstall Android Studio. After a while it starts to present these freezes kind of without explanation. Whenever I face this type of problem in the IDE I reinstall it and it returns to normal.